# Как быть если хочешь дать развернутый ответ?

Tags: предложение

За последний месяц мне попалось несколько вопросов о таймере на `javascript`. И так получилось что мне самому пришлось его делать. перед тем как начать я пробежал в поисковике все что вывелось на запрос о таймере и понял что очень часто возникают вопросы и о таймерах и особенно о таймерах обратного отсчета. У меня таймер как раз умеет все, а самое главное что я ход мысли проектирования ( если такое слово применимо к таймеру ) записал и получилось как мануал по созданию мега таймера. получилось не мало и от сюда вопрос - нужно ли выкладывать этот мануал, как ответ? И если да, то можно ли создать тему с более общим названием, чтобы охватить тему полностью?

И вообще мне нравится давать более развернутые ответы на интересные мне темы. То есть мне не было бы трудно увидев интересный вопрос, отвечать на него несколько дней (естественно не полных, а только в свободное время ), а затем выкладывать, пусть и запоздалый, но зато развернутый ответ. Но я не могу ответить на вопрос - нужно ли это `RUSO`?

Comment: можно написать вопрос с самоответом. При задании вопроса есть специальная галочка, чтобы добавить сразу и ответ. Главное чтобы заданный вопрос не получился слишком широким.

Comment: Stack Overflow вопрос не является заменой документации—хороший вопрос имеет ограниченный фокус. В качестве критерия полезности вопроса попробуйте найти вопросы, которые могут быть закрыты как точные дубликаты вашего. То есть: канонический ответ на реальные существующие вопросы—это хорошо. Если не получается найти точные дубликаты, то возможно вопрос слишком широк.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хорошие и развернутые ответы очень приветствуются.

Если Вы не видите подходящего вопроса для вашего ответа, то можно самому задать вопрос и дать к нему самоответ. Это нормальная практика.

Для таких вопросов-ответов по js подходит например метка [javascript-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-faq)

Comment: Небольшая поправка: метку javascript-faq следует ставить только если этот вопрос и правда часто возникает.